# Flutter: BouncingScrollPhysics not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Minimal code:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
  itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text('$i')),
  itemCount: 50,
)
```

The `BouncingScrollPhysics` seems to have no effect. I am testing this on macOS.

Comment: it works on windows perfectly. btw you can try `flutter clean` and rebuild

Comment: @YeasinSheikh `flutter clean`, full restart, nothing worked, however this code works on iOS. Maybe it's a bug on macOS.

Comment: Got the same problem on windows. If I fire up the Android emulator it works fine.

Comment: I'm also seeing this bug in macOS. I'm on `Flutter 3.0.5`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set parent argument. You can just set empty constructor and it will work:

```
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
```

Instead of setting physics parameter you can also use `ScrollBehavior`

```
class CustomScrollBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  const CustomScrollBehavior();
  @override
  ScrollPhysics getScrollPhysics(BuildContext context) {
     return const BouncingScrollPhysics();
  }
}

ScrollConfiguration(
        behavior: CustomScrollBehavior(),
        child: ListView.builder(
          // physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            ...
```

Comment: I already tried this (before posting question), it didn't work.

Comment: This should work. Might be cache or full restart requires. Have you checked with ScrollConfiguration?

Comment: That is basically doing the same thing and hence it also didn't work :(